# missing type-name in typedef-declaration

Tags: arduino

Hi there is an error that says: missing type-name in typedef-declaration whenever i upload the code to Arduino atmega.

```
typedef union DrsData
{
unsigned char   ucData[MAX_PACKET_SIZE-MIN_PACKET_SIZE];

 DrsRWData      stRWData;
 DrsIJogData        stIJogData;
 DrsSJogData        stSJogData; <-the error is highlighted at this line
}DrsData;
```

May I know what is wrong with this code? 
Thanks!

This is the source code including the headers.

```
#include<Arduino.h>
#include<Wire.h>
#include<Math.h> 
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>//
#define rxPin 19   // Defines the "recieve" pin for software serial to motor `enter code here`controller
#define txPin 18    // Defines the "transmit" pin for software serial to motor controller

    //CPU
    #define F_CPU 16000000

//ATmega128? ???? ?? ???? ??
#include <avr/io.h>
//interrupt? ???? ? ??? ???? ???? ??
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
//_delay_ms ? ??? ??? ???? ??
#include <util/delay.h>

#include<inttypes.h> 

#define PROTOCOL_SIZE_IDX 2
#define PROTOCOL_ID_IDX   3
#define PROTOCOL_CMD_IDX  4
#define PROTOCOL_CS1_IDX  5
#define PROTOCOL_CS2_IDX  6
#define PROTOCOL_DATA_IDX  7

#define HEADER      0xFF

//SIZE
#define MIN_PACKET_SIZE     7
#define MIN_ACK_PACKET_SIZE     9
#define MAX_PACKET_SIZE         223
#define MAX_DATA_SIZE       (MAX_PACKET_SIZE-MIN_PACKET_SIZE)

//ID ??
#define MAX_ID                  0xFD    
#define BROADCAST_ID            0xFE  

//CMD - Request Packet
#define CMD_EEP_WRITE           0x01
#define CMD_EEP_READ            0x02
#define CMD_RAM_WRITE           0x03
#define CMD_RAM_READ            0x04    
    #define CMD_RW_DATA_ADDR_IDX    7
    #define CMD_RW_DATA_LEN_IDX     8
#define CMD_I_JOG               0x05
    #define CMD_I_JOG_STRUCT_SIZE   5
    #define CMD_I_JOG_MAX_DRS       (MAX_DATA_SIZE/CMD_I_JOG_STRUCT_SIZE)
#define CMD_S_JOG                   0x06
    #define CMD_S_JOG_STRUCT_SIZE   4
    #define CMD_S_JOG_MAX_DRS       (MAX_DATA_SIZE/CMD_S_JOG_STRUCT_SIZE)
#define CMD_STAT                    0x07    
#define CMD_ROLLBACK                0x08
#define CMD_REBOOT                  0x09

#define CMD_MIN                             (CMD_EEP_WRITE)
#define CMD_MAX                             (CMD_REBOOT)

//CMD - ACK Packet
#define CMD_ACK_MASK                        0x40

#define CMD_EEP_WRITE_ACK                   (CMD_EEP_WRITE|CMD_ACK_MASK)
#define CMD_EEP_READ_ACK                    (CMD_EEP_READ|CMD_ACK_MASK)
#define CMD_RAM_WRITE_ACK                   (CMD_RAM_WRITE|CMD_ACK_MASK)
#define CMD_RAM_READ_ACK                    (CMD_RAM_READ|CMD_ACK_MASK)
#define CMD_I_JOG_ACK                       (CMD_I_JOG|CMD_ACK_MASK)
#define CMD_S_JOG_ACK                       (CMD_S_JOG|CMD_ACK_MASK)
#define CMD_STAT_ACK                        (CMD_STAT|CMD_ACK_MASK)
#define CMD_ROLLBACK_ACK                    (CMD_ROLLBACK|CMD_ACK_MASK)
#define CMD_REBOOT_ACK                      (CMD_REBOOT|CMD_ACK_MASK

#define CMD_ACK_MIN                         (CMD_EEP_WRITE_ACK)
#define CMD_ACK_MAX                         (CMD_REBOOT_ACK)

#define DrsPacket
#define stPacket
#define pstPacket
#define DrsData
 typedef struct DrsSet
  {
    unsigned char   ucStopFlag : 1;
    unsigned char   ucMode : 1;
    unsigned char   ucLedGreen : 1;
    unsigned char   ucLedBlue : 1;
    unsigned char   ucLedRed : 1;
    unsigned char   ucJogInvalid : 1;
    unsigned char   reserved : 2;
  }DrsSet;

    typedef struct DrsJog
    {   
    unsigned int    uiValue : 15;
    unsigned int    reserved : 1;
    }DrsJog;

  typedef struct DrsSJog 
  {
    DrsJog          stJog;
    DrsSet          stSet;
    unsigned char   ucId;
  }DrsSJog;

  typedef struct DrsIJog 
  {
        DrsJog          stJog;
        DrsSet          stSet;
    unsigned char   ucId;
    unsigned char   ucPlayTime;
  }DrsIJog;

  typedef struct DrsIJogData
  {
     DrsIJog            stIJog[CMD_I_JOG_MAX_DRS];
  }DrsIJogData;

  typedef struct DrsSJogData
  {
    unsigned char   ucPlayTime;
     DrsSJog            stSJog[CMD_S_JOG_MAX_DRS];
  }DrsSJogData;

  typedef struct DrsRWData
  {  
    unsigned char   ucAddress;
    unsigned char   ucLen;        
    unsigned char   ucData[MAX_DATA_SIZE-2];
  }DrsRWData;

  typedef union DrsData
  {
    unsigned char   ucData[MAX_PACKET_SIZE-MIN_PACKET_SIZE];

     DrsRWData      stRWData;
     DrsIJogData        stIJogData;
     DrsSJogData        stSJogData;
  }DrsData;

typedef struct DrsPacket 
  {
    unsigned char           ucHeader[2];
    unsigned char           ucPacketSize;
    unsigned char           ucChipID;
    unsigned char           ucCmd;
    unsigned char           ucCheckSum1;
    unsigned char           ucCheckSum2;
    union DrsData               unData;
  }DrsPacket;


//CheckSum
#define CHKSUM_MASK                         0xFE


//////////////////////////////receiving state result value //////////////////////////////
  enum{
    DRS_RXWAITING,
    DRS_RXCOMPLETE,
    DRS_HEADERNOTFOUND,
    DRS_INVALIDSIZE,
    DRS_UNKNOWNCMD,
    DRS_INVALIDID,
    DRS_CHKSUMERROR,
    DRS_RXTIMEOUT
  }DrsRxStatus;

//?? ??? ??? ??
#define USART_BUF_SIZE 256

//?? ??, ?? ???, ?? ???, ??? ?? ??? ?? ??
//USART0_EXT volatile unsigned char gucRxBuffer[USART_BUF_SIZE];
//USART0_EXT volatile unsigned char gucRxBufferReadIdx;
//USART0_EXT volatile unsigned char gucRxBufferWriteIdx;
//USART0_EXT volatile unsigned char gucRxBufferCnt;

volatile unsigned char gucRxBuffer[USART_BUF_SIZE];
volatile unsigned char gucRxBufferReadIdx;
volatile unsigned char gucRxBufferWriteIdx;
volatile unsigned char gucRxBufferCnt;

//USART0? ??? ??
void USART0_Init(unsigned long ulBaudRate);
//USART0? ?? ??? ???? ??
void USART0_PutChar(unsigned char ucData);
//USART0? ?? ?? ?? ???? ??
void USART0_PutNChar(unsigned char *pucData, unsigned char ucCnt);
//USART0? ?? ???? ?? ?? ???? ???? ??
unsigned char USART0_ucGetNChar(unsigned char *pucTarget, unsigned char ucCnt);
//USART0? ?? ???? ?? ?? ???? ??? ??
unsigned char USART0_ucTrashNChar(unsigned char ucCnt);
//USART0? ?? ??? ????? ??
void USART0_ClearBuffer(void);

void hklx_Init(unsigned long ulBaudRate);

void hklx_SendPacket( DrsPacket stPacket);

unsigned char hklx_ucReceivePacket( DrsPacket *pstPacket);

void setup()
{
  //DRS-0101? Calibrated Position ??? ???? ?? ???
typedef struct DrsCaliPos
{
    int     iPosition : 13;
    unsigned int    uiGPIO1 : 1;
    unsigned int    uiGPIO2 : 1;
    unsigned int    reserved : 1;
}

DrsCaliPos;

//Calibrated Position ??? ?? ??? ?? ???
typedef union DrsUnionCaliPos
{
     DrsCaliPos stCaliPos;
    unsigned int    uiCaliPos;
}

DrsUnionCaliPos;

//HerkuleX? ???? ?? ???
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.begin(115200);
    pinMode(rxPin, INPUT); //RX //connect to TX of motor 
    pinMode(txPin, OUTPUT); //TX //connect to RX of motor

}

  typedef struct DrsPacket 
  {
    unsigned char   ucHeader[2];
    unsigned char   ucPacketSize;
    unsigned char   ucChipID;
    unsigned char   ucCmd;
    unsigned char   ucCheckSum1;
    unsigned char   ucCheckSum2;
     DrsData        unData;
  }DrsPacket;

 // void hklx_SendPacket(DrsPacket stPacket){
void hklx_SendPacket(DrsPacket stPacket){
    unsigned char i;
        DrsPacket stPacket;

    // declare header 
    stPacket.ucHeader[0] = HEADER;
    stPacket.ucHeader[1] = HEADER;

    //CheckSum 
    stPacket.ucCheckSum1 = stPacket.ucPacketSize ^ stPacket.ucChipID ^ stPacket.ucCmd;
    for( i=0; i<(stPacket.ucPacketSize-MIN_PACKET_SIZE); i++ )    
        stPacket.ucCheckSum1 ^= stPacket.unData.ucData[i];

    stPacket.ucCheckSum2 = ~(stPacket.ucCheckSum1);
    stPacket.ucCheckSum1 &= CHKSUM_MASK;    
    stPacket.ucCheckSum2 &= CHKSUM_MASK;

    //PacketSize ?? USART0?? ??
    USART0_PutNChar(&stPacket.ucHeader[0], stPacket.ucPacketSize);

    return 0;
}
```

Full error message:

```
line 136: error: missing type-name in typedef-declaration
line 147: error: missing type-name in typedef-declaration
line 250: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'unData' with no type
line 251: error: missing type-name in typedef-declaration
line 259: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
```

Comment: Can you post the full source code, the headers you are including and the full error message as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thing: the Arduino IDE has [its own preprocessor](http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/BuildProcess) that's designed to make things easier for beginners. User-defined types is unfortunately an area where it actually makes things harder for the rest of us.

The linked page suggests placing type declarations in a separate header file. I've also had success with a technique like:

```
typedef struct _xyz {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} XYZ;

void myFunc(struct _xyz *xyzName) {
    ...
}
```

Changing the line generating the error to `struct _DrsSJogData stSJogData;` should resolve the error (given you also change `DrsSJogData`'s declaration as I suggest) but having just read Arduino's recommendation I'd go with that.

Place all type declarations in a header file separate to the main sketch and you should be fine.